# Swift Add Target class

Tags: swift

I have a class, `Listner`:

```
class Listner {
    typealias ListenerType = () -> ()
    var listeners: [ListenerType] = []

    init<V: UIControl>(view: V, event: UIControlEvents, listener: @escaping ListenerType) {
        print("Init") // Prints
        view.addTarget(self, action: #selector(actionEvent), for: event)
        self.listeners.append(listener)
    }

    @objc private func actionEvent() {
        print("EventChanged") // Does not print
        self.listeners.forEach { (listner) in
            listner()
        }
    }
}
```

that takes in a view that is a `UIControl` and adds a target to it. I know the target is added successfully because when I print `view.allTargets` I can see the just added target.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Listner(view: textField, event: .editingChanged) {
        print("listen")
    }

}
```

When I call the class like I did above and type in the textfield, `actionEvent()` is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the Listner as a member variable so that it will not go out of scope after the viewDidLoad is called. If it's a member variable then it will be called when any editing is done to your control.

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
  var listner : Listner!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.listner = Listner(view: textField, event: .allEditingEvents) {
        print("listen")
    }
  }
}
```